# how to solve System.StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, stack-overflow

hello community I have a `product class` with a property called `public_price` to which I apply functions in the get set but it throws me the `System.StackOverflowException` error, when comparing if the `detailcombo` object is different from null, why does this happen and how could I fix it?

this is my class Product:

```
 public class Producto
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ProductoId { get; set; }
        public Guid InquilinoId { get; set; }
        private string Nombre { get; set; }

        public virtual List<DetalleCombo> DetalleCombo { get; set; } 

        private decimal _PrecioPublico;
        public decimal Precio_Publico
        {
            get
            {               
                decimal total = 0;
                if (DetalleCombo != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in DetalleCombo)
                    {
                        total += item.Precio * item.Cantidad;
                    }

                    return total;
                }
                else if (DetalleGenerico != null)
                {
                    if (Usar_PrecioGenerico == true)
                    {
                        return _PrecioPublico;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var item in DetalleGenerico)
                        {
                            if (item.Es_Seleccionado == true)
                            {
                                return item.Producto.Precio_Publico;
                            }
                        }
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return _PrecioPublico;
                }
            }
            set { _PrecioPublico = value; }
        }
}
```

this is my class DetalleCombo:

```
 public class DetalleCombo
    {
        public Guid DetalleComboId { get; set; }
        public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }
        public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio { get; set; }        
    }
```

this is my class DetalleGenerico:

```
public class DetalleGenerico
    {
        public Guid DetalleGenericoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }
        public bool Es_Seleccionado { get; set; }       
    }
```

error:
[image]

Comment: Hint: set a breakpoint on the line `return item.Producto.Precio_Publico;` And learn how to use the debugger

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your setter and getters, when the debugger breaks, step into step by step and see why the getter or setter is calling itself. A stack overflow means a function, property or method is calling itself infinite times.

Comment: Strong recommendation - put most of that code into a private method which is referenced by your get section. Stronger recommendation - put a try catch around that section of code, otherwise you risk unnecessarily fatal crashes . Try catch always, but especially in get/set methods

Answer (score 2):

In this block of code:

```
foreach (var item in DetalleGenerico)
{
    if (item.Es_Seleccionado == true)
    {
        return item.Producto.Precio_Publico;
    }
}
return 0;
```

The line of code

```
return item.Producto.Precio_Publico;
```

Is causing the `Precio_Publico` property to be called endlessly.   You keep winding up in this `foreach` loop repeatedly.

Each time `Precio_Publico` is called this way, you add a stack frame to the stack, until the stack runs out of room, causing your stack overflow.

Comment: has good eyes (though looking for a recursive access to a property is the first step to solving many .NET stack overflows).  You need to change that line to `return item.Producto._PrecioPublico`.  In general, most .NET code would name that backing field either `_precioPublico` or just `precioPublico`.  If you establish a clear naming convention where fields and properties look very different to the eye, then this is less likely.

Comment: the use of lazy loading in blazor webassembly was the cause of this error

Comment: remove this line in startup .UseLazyLoadingProxies()); in my connection to the database